# Ruby: Scanning strings for matching adjacent vowel groups

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am building a script to randomly generate words that sound like english. I have broken down a large number of english words into [VCV groups](https://listserv.brown.edu/archives/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0608A&L=CONLANG&P=R1976).

> ...where the V's represent ALL the adjacent vowels in a word and the C represents ALL the adjacent consonants. For example, the English word "miniature" would become
>   "-mi", "inia", "iatu", and "ure". "school" would become "-schoo" and "ool".
>   These groups will be assembled together with other groups from other words with
>   the rule being that the complete set of adjacent ending vowels must match the
>   complete set of starting vowels for the attached group.

I have constructed a hash in the following structure:

```
pieces = { 
   :starters => { "-sma" => 243, "-roa" => 77, "-si" => 984, ...},
   :middles =>  { "iatu" => 109, "inia" => 863, "aci" => 229, ...},
   :enders =>   { "ar-" => 19, "ouid-" => 6, "ude" => 443,   ...}
}
```

In order to construct generated words, a "starter" string would need to end with the same vowel grouping as the "middle" string. The same applies when connecting the "middle" string with the "ender" string. One possible result using the examples above would be **"-sma" + "aba" + "ar-"** to give **"smabar"**. Another would be **"-si" + "inia" + "iatu" + "ude"** to give **"siniatude"**.

My problem is that when I sample any two pieces, I don't know how to ensure that the ending V group of the first piece exactly matches the beginning V group of the second piece. For example, "utua" + "uailo" won't work together because **"ua"** is not the same as **"uai"**. However, a successful pair would be "utua" + "uado" because **"ua" = "ua"**.

Comment: What do the numbers in your data structure (243, 77, 984, etc.) represent?

Comment: Relative frequency. Out of all the words analyzed, that group showed up that number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def match(first, second)
  end_of_first = first[/[aeiou]+$|[^aeiou]+$/]
  start_of_second = second[/^[aeiou]+|^[^aeiou]+/]
  end_of_first == start_of_second
end

match("utua", "uailo")
# => false
match("inia", "iatu")
# => true
```

EDIT: I apparently can't read, I thought you just want to match the group (whether vowel or consonant). If you restrict to vowel groups, it's simpler:

```
  end_of_first = first[/[aeiou]+$/]
  start_of_second = second[/^[aeiou]+/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already pre-processing the dictionary, I suggest doing a little more preprocessing to make generation simpler. I have two suggestions. First, for the starters and middles, separate each into a tuple (for which, in Ruby, we just use a two-element array) of the form (VC, V), so e.g. `"inia"` becomes `["in", "ia"]`:

```
starters = [
  [ "-sm", "a" ],
  [ "-r", "oa" ],
  [ "-s", "i" ],
  # ...
]
```

We store the starters in an array since we just need to choose one at random, which we can do with `Array#sample`:

```
starter, middle1_key = starters.sample
puts starter # => "-sm"
puts middle1_key # => "a"
```

We want to be able to look up middles by their initial V groups, so we put those tuples in a Hash instead, with their initial V groups as keys:

```
middles = {
  "ia" => [
    [ "iat", "u" ],
    [ "iabl", "e" ],
  ],
  "i" => [
    [ "in", "ia" ],
    # ...
  ],
  "a" => [
    [ "ac", "i" ],
    # ...
  ],
  # ...
}
```

Since we stored the starter's final V group in `middle1_key` above, we can now use that as a key to get the array of middle tuples whose initial V group matches, and choose one at random as we did above:

```
possible_middles1 = middles[middle1_key]
middle1, middle2_key = possible_middles1.sample
puts middle1 # => "ac"
puts middle2_key => "i"
```

Just for kicks, let's pick a second middle:

```
middle2, ender_key = middles[middle2_key].sample
puts middle2 # => "in"
puts ender_key # => "ia"
```

Our enders we don't need to store in tuples, since we won't be using any part of them to look anything up like we did with middles. We can just put them in a hash whose keys are the initial V groups and whose values are arrays of all of the enders with that initial V group:

```
enders = {
  "a" => [ "ar-", ... ],
  "oui" => [ "ouid-", ... ],
  "u" => [ "ude-", ... ],
  "ia" => [ "ial-", "iar-", ... ]
  # ...
}
```

We stored the second middle's final V group in `ender_key` above, which we can use to get the array of matching enders:

```
possible_enders = enders[ender_key]
ender = possible_enders.sample
puts ender # => "iar-"
```

Now that we have four parts, we just put them together to form our word:

```
puts starter + middle1 + middle2 + ender
# => -smaciniar-
```

#### Edit

The data structures above omit the relative frequencies (I wrote the above before I had a chance to read your answer to my question about the numbers). Obviously it's trivial to also store the relative frequencies alongside the parts, but I don't know off the top of my head a fast way to then choose parts in a weighted fashion. Hopefully my answer is of some use to you regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the methods [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), [String#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-partition), [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and a few more familiar ones:

```
def combine(arr)
  arr.flat_map { |s| s.partition /[^aeiou-]+/ }.
      chunk { |s| s }.
      map { |_, a| a.first }.
      join.delete('-')
end

combine ["-sma", "aba", "ar-"])            #=> "smabar"
combine ["-si", "inia", "iatu", "ude"]     #=> "siniatude" 
combine ["utua", "uailo", "orsua", "uav-"] #=> "utuauailorsuav"
```

To see how this works, let's look at the last example:

```
arr = ["utua", "uailo", "orsua", "uav-"]
a = arr.flat_map { |s| s.partition /[^aeiou-]+/ }
  #=> ["u", "t", "ua", "uai", "l", "o", "o", "rs", "ua", "ua", "v", "-"] 
enum = a.chunk { |s| s }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fdd14963888>:each>
```

We can see the elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["u", ["u"]], ["t", ["t"]], ["ua", ["ua"]], ["uai", ["uai"]],
  #    ["l", ["l"]], ["o", ["o", "o"]], ["rs", ["rs"]], ["ua", ["ua", "ua"]],
  #    ["v", ["v"]], ["-", ["-"]]]

b = enum.map { |_, a| a.first }
  #=> ["u", "t", "ua", "uai", "l", "o", "rs", "ua", "v", "-"] 
s = b.join
  #=> "utuauailorsuav-" 
s.delete('-')
  #=> "utuauailorsuav"
```